# Matlab syntax [explanation in C++]

Tags: c++, image, matlab, matrix, porting

I am required to port codes from Matlab to C++. However, I have many confusions on the syntax, which googling did not help me.

Following is a code snippet to read image files. Please shed some light explain what and how `[height width]` and `VolData(:, :, i)` are used in C++ terminologies.

```
%% read images
clc
clear all
cd ('..\STLBP_Matlab\test\'); % please replace "..." by your images path
a = dir('*.jpg'); % directory of images, ".jpg" can be changed, for example, ".bmp" if you use
for i = 1 : length(a)
    ImgName = getfield(a, {i}, 'name');
    Imgdat = imread(ImgName);
    if size(Imgdat, 3) == 3 % if color images, convert it to gray
        Imgdat = rgb2gray(Imgdat);
    end
    [height width] = size(Imgdat);
    if i == 1
        VolData = zeros(height, width, length(a));
    end
    VolData(:, :, i) = Imgdat;
end
cd ..
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to be converting some images to grayscale.  Here are some inline comments but note this is not syntactically correct. You will need some image processing lib most likely to load up the jpegs and get the raw data that will change the syntax.

```
a = dir('*.jpg'); % directory of images, ".jpg" can be changed, for example, ".bmp" if you use
%% we are going to loop through all of the images in this directory
for i = 1 : length(a)

    %% give me the name of the current file to process
    ImgName = getfield(a, {i}, 'name');


    %% give me the image data of the first file to process
    Imgdat = imread(ImgName);

    %% if this is an rgb image convert it to gray scale
    if size(Imgdat, 3) == 3 % if color images, convert it to gray
        Imgdat = rgb2gray(Imgdat);
    end

    %% this is a tuple. in c++ there are no tuples
    %% so it would look like this
    %% height = size(ImgData).height;
    %% width = size(ImgData).with;
    [height width] = size(Imgdat);

    %% if this is the very first object create a 3 dimensional array large enough
    %% to hold all of the images, think of it as a stack of length(a) images
    %% of a constant width and height
    if i == 1
        VolData = zeros(height, width, length(a));
    end


    %% copy all of the image data into the vol data field.
    %% this is a vector function. it's really not something in the c++ syntax
    %% in c++ this would likely be nested loops or memcopy as Amro says
    %%  int fileNumb = fileCounter++;
    %%  for (int i =0 ; i < height;i++)
    %%    for (int j=0; j < width; j++)
    %%        somearry[i][j][fileNum] = ImgData[i][j];
    VolData(:, :, i) = Imgdat;
end
```

Comment: Well, c++11 does support [tuples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/). Still it is only one line so it would probably be simpler to do it your way anyway. Anyway nice explanation.

Comment: @madmik3: btw there are no tuples in MATLAB either (I think you're confusing it with Python). Instead MATLAB can naturally return multiple variables from a function.

Answer (score 1):

The code simply reads a bunch of JPEG images from a folder (all of the same size), convert them to grayscale, then stack the images along the third dimension to build what I think is a volume data array. This array will be of size height-by-width-by-N, where N the number of images.

In C/C++, you would just allocate a buffer array of that size, and copy the pixels of each image one after the other (in row-major order because that's the convention in C). You could do this efficiently with something like `memcpy`.